# Can I replace a usb micro b connector with JST xh connector?

Tags: usb

I am working on a project where stm32 HID device is connected to a PC using USB cable. There is no need for unplugging on the product side, so can I replace a usb connector with JST one or directly solder it on board? Does the metal part of micro usb play a role in data transfer?

Comment: This has been done in at least [one product I'm using](https://shop.aquacomputer.de/product_info.php?products_id=3773&language=en), with the connector available to the customer. I own a bigger version of that device and it works pretty nicely.

Comment: The metal part connects the shield which helps with EMC but does not itself carry data. if you need the shield on your device just use another connector pin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of USB devices such as keyboards or mice have a captive cable which either has a custom connector is directly soldered to board.

The Micro USB connector itself plays no role in the data transfer.